# why theme editor page is not opening of a website in my laptop?

Tags: javascript, php, themes, editor, extent

i want to edit theme of a website from control panel bt that page of theme editor is not opening in any browser in my laptop. popup is coming saying "To use the theme editor, access with a laptop or desktop device". plz help regarding this any one

opening of theme editor page

Answer (score 0):

although I've not understand your problem clearly.
See, if you want to edit the theme of your website from the website control panel, and unable to do that, then please try to clear your browser cache and make a hard reload. This could help you.

Now, if you're using any CMS like WordPress then wait a bit and refresh the cache from the cPanel or the hosting. I've faced this kind of problem too and refreshing the cache like that helped me too. So, you can check it in that way.

Also it could be the problem of the browser. So, if this doesn't works, try a different browser.